# Looking for the Google Sheets Shortcut for Moving Decimal Point Right / Left

Tags: google-sheets

Does anyone know the shortcut for moving decimal point left/right?

I use Google Sheets via Chrome on a mac, but the shortcut on other platforms would be useful as well.

Comment: An AI tool said that `alt` + `ctl` + `shift` + `.` / `,` would do this, but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

As described in https://www.automateexcel.com/how-to/move-decimal-places/, you can use a **Custom number format** with format `0"."00`, but I doubt that a keyboard shortcut exists...

Answer (score 1):

[Google's Keyboard Shortcuts Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cpc-shortcuts) does not list such a feature.

| Format cells |  |
| --- | --- |
| Bold | **Ctrl + B** |
| Underline | **Ctrl + U** |
| Italic | **Ctrl + I** |
| Strikethrough | **Alt + Shift + 5** |
| Centre align | **Ctrl + Shift + E** |
| Left align | **Ctrl + Shift + L** |
| Right align | **Ctrl + Shift + R** |
| Apply top border | **Alt + Shift + 1** |
| Apply right border | **Alt + Shift + 2** |
| Apply bottom border | **Alt + Shift + 3** |
| Apply left border | **Alt + Shift + 4** |
| Remove borders | **Alt + Shift + 6** |
| Apply outer border | **Alt + Shift + 7** **Ctrl + Shift + 7** |
| Insert link | **Ctrl + K** |
| Insert time | **Ctrl + Shift + ;** |
| Insert date | **Ctrl + ;** |
| Insert date and time | **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + ;** |
| Format as decimal | **Ctrl + Shift + 1** |
| Format as time | **Ctrl + Shift + 2** |
| Format as date | **Ctrl + Shift + 3** |
| Format as currency | **Ctrl + Shift + 4** |
| Format as percentage | **Ctrl + Shift + 5** |
| Format as exponent | **Ctrl + Shift + 6** |
| Clear formatting | Ctrl + \ |